# Where can i find the C++ stl map implementation in C?

Tags: c, dictionary, stl

Where can i find the C++ STL map implementation in C?Is Red Black Tree code which is used in c++ STL available in C language?

Comment: "Where can I find the apple tree for oranges." You were already told they are different languages. Please do some research on your own how to implement that algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The code used to implement STL containers differs by compiler, but for all compilers, it's *heavily* dependent on C++ features (in particular, templates and classes with complex inheritance for implementation hiding, etc.). It's usually completely unreadable; trying to use it as a base for C code is only going to end in tears.

If you want red black tree code, might I suggest looking for implementations already written in C, e.g. [this MIT alum's code](http://web.mit.edu/~emin/Desktop/ref_to_emin/www.old/source_code/red_black_tree/index.html).

Comment: you can specialize it for `std::map<void *,void *>` and export to C though :)

Comment: @Slava: Except `map` is ordered, and templated on the comparison function; a value of `void*` is reasonable, but using `void*` as a key isn't likely to be support whatever arbitrary sorting you're interested in. (Explaining for others, I assume you were joking) Generalizing with a C-style string key would cover a lot of cases, so `std::map<const char*, void*>` might not be wholly useless.

Comment: Comparison function can also be provided through pointer to function from c. Who knows about joking...

Comment: @Slava  Can you please elaborate on this :"you can specialize it for std::map<void *,void *> and export to C though 
?

Comment: @Dr.John I think it is pretty obvious, you create structure with `std::map<void*,void*,...>` in it and set of `export "C"` functions that accept pointer to that structure and forward logic - search/insert/remove etc. It probably should have a pointer to comparator function `bool compare( const void *, const void * )`. Or if you only need particular type then it is simpler. I am not sure this is practical though.

Comment: @Dr.John: It means you need to compile part of your project (the part wrapping `std::map<void *,void *>` in a set of C functions) as C++ (so it understands `std::map<void *,void *>`), with a header that defines all those C functions with `extern "C"` wrapping (when compiled under C++), so they get C like names. Then you compile the rest of your code as C, including that header and linking the obj, and use the API defined in the header. It's ugly though, and rarely worth it; if you're willing to partially compile in C++, it's usually simpler to just do everything in C++.

Comment: @Slava: I think you meant `extern "C"`, not `export "C"`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes of course `extern`, thanks.